# BJT Common Emitter Positive Power Gain

Tags: amplifier, bjt, common-emitter

I am trying to complete a simple amplifier project using a single transistor common emitter amplifier. I understand that the common emitter is inverting but I need the power gain to be positive. The requirement is to get +10db power gain but I'm getting -24db since it's inverting. Is there any easy way to make the gain positive? Thanks.
[image: Schematic]

---

```
Vcc vcc 0 5

* Input block (DO NOT CHANGE). Your input node is called "vi".
vsig vsig 0 ac 1
Rsig vsig 1 10k
CCi 1 vi 1

* Output block (DO NOT CHANGE). Your output node is called "vo".
CCo vo vl 1
RL vl 0 1k

* Transistor 
Q1 vo vi 2 Q2N3904

* Your circuit. Enter your elements below, using vi as the input node, vo, as the output node, and vcc as the power supply.
R1 vi vcc 10k
R2 vi 0 1200
Rc vo 0 7k
Re 2 0 1200

CCe 2 0 1
gp: sqrt(v(vl)*i(rl)/(v(vsig)*i(vsig)))=(-35.6014dB,-89.8774°) at 1000`
```

Comment: A negative power gain has nothing to do with your circuit being an inverting amplifier.

Comment: Well compared to the CB & CC, the CE is the only one with a negative voltage gain which causes it to be negative power gain. I'm not sure how to make it positive @W5VO

Comment: You're mis-using decibels. Saying you're amplifier has a gain of -24 dB is is saying that the gain of your amplifier is 10^(-2.4) or P(in) = ~0.003 P(out), which is not an amplifier at all. You mean to say that your circuit has a gain of 24 dB, but with reverse polarity.

Comment: Unfortunately my professor will not accept a negative decibel so I need to start over since I can't figure how to make it positive @Alex

Comment: Show your calculations.

Comment: Tried to put the netlist and power gain I'm getting but it put it as one paragraph hah, as you can tell I'm getting -35db which wont be accepted @transistor

Comment: I put your diagram into the schematic editor/simulator available here on the site.  You are getting negative gain.  This is NOT because the output is inverted. @uint128_t has explained that thoroughly.  You are getting negative gain from poor choices for the various components.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Alex's and W5VO's comments:

An inverting amplifier does not imply a negative power gain. Power is the absolute value of current times voltage through the load, \$P = \left|IV\right|\$ (an amplifier producing negative power has *issues*).

For instance, if I was to design an inverting buffer (gain of -1), you could also express that as a gain of 0dB with a phase shift of 180º.

However, this is completely independent of power gain.

Let's say the input impedance of the inverting buffer is 1MΩ, and the input signal is 1V. Then the power in is \$P_{IN} = 1\text{uW}\$.

Let's say the output has zero output impedance and it is driving a load of 10Ω. So the load sees -1V, and current through the load is -100mA.

However, the power dissipated in the load is \$P_{OUT} = \frac{V^2}{R} = \frac{(-1V)^2}{10\Omega} = 100\text{mW}\$, a *positive* quantity.

The power gain is \$\frac{P_{IN}}{P_{OUT}} = 1E5 = 50\text{dB}\$, a *very large positive quantity*.

I'll leave it to you to work out the power gain for your amplifier, but the point is that the sign of the voltage gain has nothing to do with the power gain.

Comment: Ok, as i commented earlier I have a netlist that I've filled out with my drawing and the power gain is provided by `gp: sqrt(v(vl)*i(rl)/(v(vsig)*i(vsig)))=(-35.6014dB,-89.8774°) at 1000` So -35dB is the power gain I'm getting, so this suppose to be absolute like you're pointing out? I'm just trying to make sure it's correct because my prof explicitly said if its a negative power gain it would be incorrect which seems odd now.

Comment: Maybe you should find \$V_L\$ as a function of \$V_{sig}\$, as well as \$I_{sig}\$. Then you can calculate \$P_{IN}\$ and \$P_L\$ directly.